# Fill in NA values based on beginning/end value in data frame

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I currently have a data frame with start and end values. I need them to "fill in" between the start and end value. The caveat: There are many values that still need to remain NA.

Context: I am tracking events that go for a certain number of days. For example (seen below), an event may go for 3 days, or it may go for 6. On the other hand, if there was no event during a set of days, I need that to remain NA.

Below is the current situation:

```
Date        value event event_detail
2017-03-30  12    NA    NA
2017-03-31  14    NA    NA
2017-04-01  15    A     Y
2017-04-02  20    NA    NA
2017-04-03  17    A     Y
2017-04-04  20    NA    NA
2017-04-05  14    NA    NA
```

This is what I would like:

```
Date        value event event_detail
2017-03-30  12    NA    NA
2017-03-31  14    NA    NA
2017-04-01  15    A     Y
2017-04-02  20    A     Y
2017-04-03  17    A     Y
2017-04-04  20    NA    NA
2017-04-05  14    NA    NA
```

The tricky situation is that after, say, April 3rd, there may not be an event for some time and I do not want the event "A" or the detail "Y" filled in.

Any ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your desire is just to pass a value backwards in time, then `zoo::na.locf()` (Last Observation Carried Forward) has an option that can do this (basically it becomes Next Observation Carried Backward).

```
library(zoo)

mydata <- 
    data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
               Date = c("1/04/2017", "2/04/2017", "3/04/2017", "4/04/2017",
                        "5/04/2017"),
               value = c(15L, 20L, 17L, 20L, 14L),
               event = c("A", NA, "A", NA, NA),
               event_detail = c("Y", NA, "Y", NA, NA)
               )

mydata$event <- na.locf(mydata$event, fromLast = TRUE, na.rm = FALSE)
mydata$event_detail <- na.locf(mydata$event_detail, fromLast = TRUE, na.rm = FALSE)

mydata

       Date value event event_detail
1 1/04/2017    15     A            Y
2 2/04/2017    20     A            Y
3 3/04/2017    17     A            Y
4 4/04/2017    20  <NA>         <NA>
5 5/04/2017    14  <NA>         <NA>
```

Remember to sort your data before you do this!

Edit: Just saw you had the `dplyr` tag also. Here's that:

```
mydata %<>%
    mutate_at(vars(starts_with("event")), na.locf, fromLast = TRUE, na.rm = FALSE)
```

---

You can also limit the range of `na.locf` if you **know** the size of your gaps is going to be smaller than the size of the periods between observations.

```
mydata <- 
    data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
               Date = c("30/03/2017", "31/03/2017", "1/04/2017", "2/04/2017",
                        "3/04/2017", "4/04/2017", "5/04/2017"),
               value = c(12L, 14L, 15L, 20L, 17L, 20L, 14L),
               event = c(NA, NA, "A", NA, "A", NA, NA),
               event_detail = c(NA, NA, "Y", NA, "Y", NA, NA)
    )

mydata %<>%
    mutate_at(vars(starts_with("event")), na.locf, fromLast = TRUE, 
              na.rm = FALSE, maxgap = 1)

mydata

        Date value event event_detail
1 30/03/2017    12  <NA>         <NA>
2 31/03/2017    14  <NA>         <NA>
3  1/04/2017    15     A            Y
4  2/04/2017    20     A            Y
5  3/04/2017    17     A            Y
6  4/04/2017    20  <NA>         <NA>
7  5/04/2017    14  <NA>         <NA>
```

Comment: This is close but not quite what I need, since I do not need every last value carried back. I have edited the original post for clarity, let me know if this makes sense. For context: the full data set has other "guiding" information such as organization ID codes, so what I am looking to do is fill in "the middle" of the event/event detail for given organizations. I appreciate the help.

Comment: If you **know** that the gap is only going to be of size 1 and the desired NA gaps are larger, you can still use `na.locf` but bound it with `maxgap`.

`mutate_at(vars(starts_with("event")), na.locf, fromLast = TRUE, na.rm = FALSE, maxgap = 1)` does what you showed in your new example.

Comment: Perfect! Quick follow-up, let's say I know that a certain event type lasts 20 days (call it event = B). Is there a way to include a filter in the dplyr piping to accomplish that?

Comment: Accomplish what exactly?

Comment: Fill in the information in event & event detail. In other words, if I know event B always will have 6 blank spaces (where A had 1), and event C will always have 10 blank spaces, can I fill in for the different event types? Thanks!

Comment: I haven't tested this code, but explore a thought process like `mutate_at(vars(starts_with("event")), funs(ifelse(. == "B", na.locf(., maxgap = 6), .))`  for each case.